# If $A$ and $B$ are compact with $(I-A)^{-1}$ bounded, then is $I + (I-A)^{-1}B$ invertible?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, banach-spaces

Let $A:X\to X$ where $X$, is a Banach space, be a compact operator with a bounded inverse $(I-A)^{-1}$. Then if $B$ is a compact operator, is the the following operator invertible (and if so, is it bounded):
$$
T = I + (I-A)^{-1}B
$$
It 'feels' like it should be but I don't know how to show it.

Comment: Is $(I-A)^{-1}$ really an inverse to $A$? Also is it really the boundedness of $T$ (if it's invertible) that's the question?

Comment: Actually, boundedness is not important, I just want to know if its invertible?

Comment: Yes, but $(I-A)^{-1}$ being the inverse of $A$ sounds as an odd prerequisite. That would mean that $A=I/2$...

Comment: Even in the simplest case $X = \mathbb R$ there are plenty of examples where this operator is not invertible!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not show it ! Take $A=0$. If you are right, then it means that $I+B$ is invertible for each(!) compact operator $B$. But this is not the case.